# Sumifs for multiple vertical and horizontal criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I would have to summarize data followingly:

Criterias are: date in the vertical axis, and the unit and name in the horizontal axis:

I would have to get a sum for Customer 1, main category and for time-period of 11/2020 - 12/2021

[image: example of the situation]

Thanks for help!

Comment: Use SUMIFS and INDEX/MATCH or XLOOKUP.

Comment: Can you provide an example how the index/match would work in the example sheet?

Comment: A follow-up question: are the values in column B dates, or text?

Comment: they are now dates (values)

Comment: Something like: `=SUMIFS(INDEX(C:F,,MATCH("Customer 1",$C$1:$F$1,0)),B:B,">="&DATE(2020,11,1),B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,12,31))`. You don't necessarily have to use `DATE`, but it's an example. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvmfY.png

Comment: @BigBen Sir, if you dont mind please post the solution in Answer. The solution is amazing, i just want upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `SUMPRODUCT` Function as well

Formula used in cell J7

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LOOKUP(COLUMN($D$1:$H$1),COLUMN($D$1:$H$1)/
($D$1:$H$1<>""),$D$1:$H$1)=$J$3)*($J$4=$D$3:$H$3)*
($J$5<=$B$4:$B$21)*($J$6>=$B$4:$B$21)*($D$4:$H$21))
```

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming column B contains dates, you can use `SUMIFS` and `INDEX/MATCH`:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(C:F,,MATCH("Customer 1",$C$1:$F$1,0)),B:B,">="&DATE(2020,11,1),B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,12,31))
```

Adjust the columns in `C:F` and `$C$1:$F$1` as needed.

[image]

The `DATE` is not necessary:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(C:F,,MATCH("Customer 1",$C$1:$F$1,0)),B:B,">=11/1/2020",B:B,"<=12/31/2021")
```

If you want to get "Other" for example, just add 1 to the result of `MATCH`:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(C:F,,MATCH("Customer 1",$C$1:$F$1,0)+1),B:B,">=11/1/2020",B:B,"<=12/31/2021")
```

Comment: Sir, `INDEX` & `MATCH` is just elegant, thank you for the share!

Comment: Sir, one thing as in OP's query the `Customer 1` or `Customer 2` might be used in a merged cell or may be its cross aligned, then how to use this formula, then can I use this within `MATCH` Function `LOOKUP(COLUMN($D$1:$H$1),COLUMN($D$1:$H$1)/($D$1:$H$1<>""),$D$1:$H$1)`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya - if it's a merged cell, then the match returns the position of the leftmost cell, where the value actually is... so the `MATCH` as-is works as expected, there's no need to adjust it.